# displaying dropdown list of those items which are not there in the table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table called `home` which has `column_id` as a column ,i want to display dropdown items say(column 1 and/or column2 and/or column3)  which are not there in `home` table.

Comment: put some example and table structure

Comment: i have a home page with 3 columns, i want to add description to those columns. i am adding description from another page where i will write insert code.i want to have a drop down on this page of those items whose description is not there in home page.

Answer (score 1):

Execute a query like below,

```
$query = select * from home where description ='' or description is NULL;
```

Process the above query and send the items to your HTML page to display in the dropdown. I hope this is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your problem try this

```
  <select>
    <?php
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT column_id FROM `your_table` WHERE description='' ") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['column_id'].'">Column-'.$row['column_id'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```